# How to display data in a gridview which selected by a dropdown list

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2013

I have 2 Gridviews (tableA and tableB) and 1 dropdownlist (ddlYear)
tableA have a lists of staff number and name. When select a staff from tableA, data of the staff will display in tableB 
(tableB header have year,qty, rate). And it will only display the current year (past year will not be display on tableB).

This is where dropdownlist comes in. When i select past year '2014' from the dropdownlist, tableB will display 2014 data on that particular staff which was selected. How to display data in tableB when past year is selected from ddl?

*I just show some parts of the code, so you can get the idea:*

- you can just show example statement. No need to be the same as my data.

Comment: Ok. i am able to solve the issue in another method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few changes in code and it would work.

Add an additional parameter in you method to pass year:
  LoadGridTableB(Year As Int, Optional sortExpression As String = "")

Call the method on your drop-down list's change event by passing current selected value like this:
 LoadGridTableB(Convert.ToInt(ddl.SelectedValue), Optional sortExpression As String = "")